# How does Flash calculate a DisplayObject's dimensions based on the children?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a class called Container which extends Sprite and adds the ability to set width and height manually, with scaleX and scaleY always remaining 1.

I have put such a class into a sprite and noticed the sprite measures itself by internal calculations, not actually getting width / height from the getters.

What is this math and how can I extend it to force the Sprite to consider my extended width and height getters while doing its internal measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math lies within `getBoundary()` function that's called for all of the children and its own graphics to determine the coordinates for the edges of the entire sprite's display list. That's why setting width without scaling might not be useful. But if you still wish to do this, first make fields that will contain info on set width and height, which you will update on `container.width` and `container.height` assignment, then you also override getters on width and height, returning maximum of stored width/height and calls of `super.width` and `super.height`.

```
var storedWidth:Number=0; // to not have NaNs
public override function get width():Number {
    var w:Number=super.width; // get width from that math
    if (storedWidth>w) w=storedWidth; // or any other logic, to operate these values
    return w;
}
```

The same approach with height.

Comment: I do use NaN as a placeholder for storedWidth. If storedWidth is NaN, I use super.width, else use storedWidth, even if its lower than super.width. I will do some research on getBoundary(). Thank you.